# Single Line of Text column showing extra 12 decimals

Tags: single-line-of-text

I have a SharePoint site that only contains excel files. The column in question is a single line of text and the data shows 12 trailing zeros after the decimal point, which is an eyesore. Most of the data in the column is numbers, but there is an occasional number/letter combination, so I can't change it to a Number column. Is there a way to make force the column to exclude all those trailing zeroes? Either with a setting or using JSON? I would even be OK modifying all 500+ files if I knew what to change.

[image]

Comment: Are you adding data in this column manually from powerapps / power Automate flow or any other tool?

Comment: I am not using any powerapps or flows, I am just reading the data from the excel files. Each excel file has a ranged name called "Test_Cell". Then I created a Custom Document Property (named "Test Cell") that is linked to that ranged name. SharePoint is looking at that Custom Document Property to pull the data for this column (which is also called "Test Cell")